# Is it possible to populate a react-bootstrap Form input tag with a previously stored value in a MERN app?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, mern, react-bootstrap-form

I'm making a mern app, where I want to add a max number input field. I want that after login the previously stored value in the database is displayed in that input tag.

I have already created the UI using react-bootstrap Form element